# конструирование контейнера из потока ввода

Tags: c++

Конструировать и инициализировать вектор можно различными способами. Например можно создать вектор двумя итераторами другого контейнера:

```
std::list<int> list{3, 5, 6, 7, 8};
std::vector<int> v1,  v2(list.begin(), list.end());
```

можно также заполнить его  прямо из потока ввода:

```
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), 
          std::istream_iterator<int>(), std::back_inserter(v1));
```

Вопрос:  почему же  нельзя конструировать вектор из потока ввода, как с первым примером? Например, если написать:

```
std::vector<int> 
v3(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), std::istream_iterator<int>());
for (int i : v3)
    std::cout << i <<' ';
```

то выдается ошибка:

```
/* error: no matching function for call to
 'begin(std::vector<int> (&)(std::istream_iterator<int>, std::istream_iterator<int> (*)()))'
      for (int i : v3)
                 ^*/
```

Comment: Странно. У меня все работает: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d7b3c04879a2589f

Comment: вот и мне странно, потому и спросил

Comment: Так а что за компилятор так ругается?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дело не в конструировании и инициализации вектора.

Ваше сообщение об ошибке говорит о том, что ваше объявление `v3` было проинтерпретировано как *объявление функции*. Это [похоже на] баг (?) компилятора. Он неправильно (?) обработал most vexing parse.

Замените хотя бы внешние `()` на `{}` в инициализации

```
std::vector<int> 
v3{ std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), std::istream_iterator<int>() };
```

Что интересно, таким "багом" страдают MSVC++ и Clang. Кто же тут прав? Эта тема здесь уже всплывала, но что-то я не могу ее найти.

Также: [Most vexing parse with a qualified-id - or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28955859/most-vexing-parse-with-a-qualified-id-or-not)

Comment: и что же делать? Менять компилятор?

Comment: да, так сработает, но все таки странно, решил работать в QT  и на тебе...

Comment: Интересная ситуация. Clang выдает другую ошибку, он ругается на `::` в `std::cin`, которое кажется ему именем параметра.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: MSVC++ тоже: "error C2751: 'std::cin': the name of a function parameter cannot be qualified". Что за компилятор использовал автор вопроса?

Comment: @AnT Если я правильно помню, у автора стоит какая-то старая VS (2011 или что-то в этом роде).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Хм... А разве MSVC++ когда-то ставил `^` в своих сообщениях об ошибке? "no matching function for call to" - больше похоже на GCC.

Comment: @AnT, Да, это GCC, я иногда в QT работаю, а там  установлен этот .  Спасибо, все выяснил

Answer (score 5):

Конструировать напрямую из `istream_iterator` можно, но судя по сообщению об ошибке, тут сработал *most vexing parse*.

---

C точки зрения вашего компилятора, строка

```
std::vector<int> v3(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), std::istream_iterator<int>());
```

выглядит одновременно как

1. определение переменной `v3` типа `std::vector<int>` и
2. объявление функции `v3` с возвращаемым типом `std::vector<int>` и двумя параметрами:

   - типа `std::istream_iterator<int>` с именем `std::cin`. Скобки вокруг имени игнорируются.

     Но `::` в имени параметра - нонсенс. Насколько я понимаю, тут компилятор неправ - имя параметра не может содержать `::`.
     GCC 8.2 компилирует эту строчку без ошибок, а Clang 7 ругается на `::`. И то и другое явно более правильно. (Поведение GCC кажется мне более разумным, но я не знаю, что по этому поводу говорит стандарт.)
   - типа `std::istream_iterator<int> (*)()` (указатель на функцию без аргументов, возвращающую `std::istream_iterator<int>`).

     В исходной строке звездочки не было, но параметры, являющиеся функциями, автоматически преобразуются в указатели на функции. (Подобно тому, как параметры-массивы преобразуются в указатели.)

В таких случаях компилятор всегда истолковывает такие неоднозначные конструкции как объявления функций. Это и называется "most vexing parse", то есть "наиболее раздражающий парсинг" (потому что это часто застает программистов врасплох).

Чтобы исправить ошибку, нужно изменить строчку так, чтобы она явно не выглядела как объявление функции.

Например так:

```
std::vector<int> v3(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), std::istream_iterator<int>{});
```

Или так:

```
std::vector<int> v3((std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin)), std::istream_iterator<int>());
```